# Select option with links in React

Tags: html, reactjs, hyperlink

I want to open a pdf files in a single frame. When the user choose option(pdf page) from select tag the pdf page should appear in the iframe tag.[frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDJUN.png)

```
      <select id="EHealth" name="EHealth" className="optionsEHealth" required>
    <option className="optionEHealth"></option>
    <option value="vpn" className="optionStyle"><Link to={vpn} target="iframe-EH">VPN Form</Link></option>

   </select>

   <iframe name="iframe-EH" className="iframe-form" src="" 
         height="1100rem" 
        width="900rem" title="">
        </iframe>
```

Comment: And why would you use `Link` for that instead of changing iframe's source?

Comment: This is the iframe

Comment: Add `onChange` listener and redirect in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the Link inside the select option is not valid. It will not be hyperlink and never trigger any link events. So you should be using select on Change event and then in that change event set iframe source. To get dom node access you can use `useRef`

You can set option value as URL and then that will be set in to iframe.

```
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select
        id="EHealth"
        name="EHealth"
        className="optionsEHealth"
        required
        onChange={(e) => {
          ref.current.src = e.target.value ? e.target.value : "";
        }}
      >
        <option className="optionEHealth"></option>
        <option
          value="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579353978004-434ec5670319?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=880&q=80"
          className="optionStyle"
        >
          VPN Form
        </option>
        <option
          value="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612505890061-5235f9f9e3a9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=880&q=80"
          className="optionStyle"
        >
          Image
        </option>
      </select>
      <br />
      <br />
      <iframe
        ref={ref}
        name="iframe-EH"
        className="iframe-form"
        src=""
        height="1100rem"
        width="900rem"
        title="iframe-EH"
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Updated answer to use multiple options with different URLs. Repeat the same.